# Using basestring in is instance - Type mismatch warning

Tags: python, pycharm, typechecking, isinstance

[image: Warning for isinstance]

The warning is:
Expected type 'Union[type, Tuple[type, ...]]', got 'Union[str, unicode]' instead.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't think you're doing something wrong, this seems like a problem with pycharm. Or did you redefine `basestring`? And another question: You're using python 2.7, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is a known bug. Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23470

Comment: Thanks user2235698.